# How to access Cosmos DB "Analytical Storage" Preview?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I tried to sign up for the "Analytical Storage" preview feature in the Azure Portal for my Cosmos DB account in North Europe. However it has been stuck in "Pending" state for two weeks now. Is this feature still available and if so how can I get it enabled?

Also how is the analytical storage accessed? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/globally-distributed-transactional-analytical-storage it's “Apache Spark”. Does this refer to the Cosmos DB Spark Connector or how do you query the underlying Parquet files? Also will it be possible to move the Parquet files to external storage (e.g. ADLS) for consumption by other BI tools?

Answer (score 0):

Analytical Storage is currently a gated preview. This should go to public preview sometime this Summer.

The storage itself is fully managed so you will not be able to access the parquet files or storage directly. The only way to access this will be through the Synapse Analytics service.

thanks.